# Python: Costing calculator output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Good day all

I'm busy creating a small costing calculator for the signage department.
I'm not getting the calculator to output the amount.

Brief Description:
You enter the height and width and then when you hit enter it needs to display the cost.

How do I get it to work? Any suggestions please and thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Define the Functions here
def squeare(height,width):
    cost = ((float(height) * float(width))/1000000 * 650 * 1.15 * 1.50)
    return cost

window = Tk()
window.title("Costing Calculator V1.0")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(window, padding="20 20 20 20")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

height = StringVar()
width = StringVar()

#ttk.Label(mainframe, text="H").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)
height_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=height)
height_entry.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=(W,E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="X").grid(column=5, row=1, sticky=E)

#ttk.Label(mainframe, text="W").grid(column=6, row=1, sticky=E)
width_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=width)
width_entry.grid(column=7, row=1, sticky=(W,E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="=").grid(column=8, row=1, sticky=E)

#call function
#squeare()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you add the specific problem you are running into and perhaps an error message. This is very broad at the moment

Comment: @SvenHarris it's running so I can add the height & width but upon hitting enter nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have bound the window frame with the return key. There is an empty *result* label. Whenever you press the enter key, its *text* will be updated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def squeare(height, width):
    cost = float(height) * float(width)/1000000 * 650 * 1.15 * 1.50
    result.configure(text=str(cost))

window = Tk()
window.title("Costing Calculator V1.0")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(window, padding="20 20 20 20")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

height = StringVar()
height.set(0)
width = StringVar()
width.set(0)

height_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=height)
height_entry.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="we")

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="X").grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="e")

width_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=width)
width_entry.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=(W,E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="=").grid(column=3, row=0, sticky="e")
result = ttk.Label(mainframe)
result.grid(row=0, column=4)

window.bind('<Return>', lambda e: squeare(height.get(), width.get()))

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank all of you I will review my code and see where I was in the wrong. I appreciate the very quick assistance from all

Comment: @LouisBotha Sure. Just edited my code to take care of the default values as well.

Answer (score 0):

The is to catch the 'enter' event for the second input field.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Define the Functions here
def squeare(height,width):
    cost = ((float(height) * float(width))/1000000 * 650 * 1.15 * 1.50)
    result.configure(text=str(cost))


def enter(event=None):
    squeare(height.get(), width.get())

window = Tk()
window.title("Costing Calculator V1.0")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(window, padding="20 20 20 20")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

height = StringVar()
width = StringVar()

#ttk.Label(mainframe, text="H").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)
height_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=height)
height_entry.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=(W,E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="X").grid(column=5, row=1, sticky=E)

#ttk.Label(mainframe, text="W").grid(column=6, row=1, sticky=E)
width_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=width)
width_entry.grid(column=7, row=1, sticky=(W,E))

width_entry.bind('<Return>',enter)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="=").grid(column=8, row=1, sticky=E)
result = ttk.Label(mainframe, text="")
result.grid(column=9, row=1, sticky=E)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Uwe Ziegenhagen it works just displaying the result in on the GUIs window, not in it.

Comment: Place a result label east to the "=" label and use the `configure` method of the label. I updated my code